# howto calculate the size of a CGRect to fit with a text ( IOS , swift )

Tags: ios, swift, text-size

I draw a text in my view and this works fine.

Now how can I calculate the width of my text, which is drawn ?

My code :
In my code I have defined "iBoxLength", which is the assumed size of the text and is well-proportioned (too large) .

```
           let fieldColor: UIColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
            let fieldFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: fTextSize)
            var paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            //var textalign = NSTextAlignment.Center;

            paraStyle.lineSpacing = 6.0
            paraStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
            var skew = 0.1

            let attributes = [
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fieldColor,
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paraStyle,
                NSObliquenessAttributeName: skew,
                //NSTextAlignment: textalign,
                NSFontAttributeName: fieldFont!
            ]

            s.drawInRect(CGRectMake(CGFloat(Float(iTextPositionX)-Float(iBoxLength/2)), CGFloat(iTextPositionY), CGFloat(iBoxLength), CGFloat(10)), withAttributes: attributes)

var Textwidth:Float = getWidth(s); // <------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` has a `sizeWithAttributes()` method:

```
let text = NSString("myText")
let textSize = text.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)
```

See: [NSString UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:)